# display the armstrong number between the range specified by users using function..some advice in this please to get the result

Tags: c

////program to display armstrong numbers in given range by user and display their counts::::use of function and display from the main/////

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int arm(int );
void main()
{
    int a,b,i,x,c=0,j;
    printf("enter the range\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    for(i=a;i<b;i++)                                        ///loop to transfer all the number of range to function arm/////
    {
        i=j;
        x=arm(j);                                           //calling function//
        if(x==i)
        {
            printf("%d\t",x);                               ///printing armstrong numbers///
            c++;                                            ///counting armstrong numbers/// 
        }
    }
    printf("the number of armstrong numbers is:%d",c);      ///printing counts//
}
```

---

```
int arm(int j)                                               
{
    int sum=0,z;
    while(j>0)                                              ///armstrong number process loop///
    {
        z=j%10;
        sum=sum+z*z*z;
        j=j/10;
    }
    return sum;                                             ///return the value of sum obtained from while loop//
}
```

Comment: Kindly Explain what problem you are getting.

Comment: the code is running but when i give range like (50 t0 200) nothing happens in the output screen. it just take the input and is over. no errors nothing it just stays there.

Comment: Abhi change `i=j;` to `j=i;` in for loop.

Comment: @Himanshu thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have done 1 mistake in your code.

In for loop you need to assign value of `i` to `j` i.e `j = i`

But you are doing reverse, that is the problem.

Use `j=i;` instead of `i=j;`